# Why won't clang compile my code?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, migration, clang, nswindow

Before, I used `gcc`, and the following compiled fine. Using `clang` however, I get the following error:

```
MyWindow.mm:37:25: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 
                          'id<NSTextViewDelegate>' with an lvalue of type 
                          'NSWindow *'
  [textView setDelegate:win];  
                        ^~~
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What the compiler is saying is that `NSWindow` isn't implementing `NSTextViewDelegate`.

Probably your subclass that is actually stored in the NSWindow pointer is, in which case you should try;

```
[textView setDelegate:(MyRealWindowClass*)win]
```